# Possible to start a RAID1 setup with a single drive?

Tags: zfs, raid1, proxmox

Can I start a ZFS pool with a RAID1 setup using a single drive, and then add another one later?

Running Proxmox VE 7.2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can!

Follow the step-by-step guide below.

**"Add a Mirror to an Existing ZFS Drive"**

https://blog.fosketts.net/2017/12/11/add-mirror-existing-zfs-drive/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can start a ZFS pool with a single drive in Proxmox and then add another drive later to set up a RAID 1 (mirror) configuration. This process is known as "disk expansion" or "pool expansion."

Here's an overview of the steps you would need to follow:

1. Create a ZFS pool with a single drive: You can create a ZFS pool
   using a single drive in Proxmox by following the normal process for
   creating a ZFS pool. The pool will start as a single-disk pool.
2. Add a second drive: Once the ZFS pool is created, you can add a
   second drive to the pool. To do this, you would need to physically
   add the second drive to the system and then use the `zpool add`
   command to add the new disk to the pool.
3. Convert the pool to a mirror: After the second disk is added to the
   pool, you can convert the pool to a mirror configuration using the
   `zpool attach` command. This will cause ZFS to start mirroring data
   across the two disks, providing redundancy and increased data
   availability.

Keep in mind that adding a second drive to an existing ZFS pool is a disruptive process, as the data on the first drive will need to be copied to the second drive in order to set up the mirror. Additionally, you will need to have enough free space on the first drive to accommodate the data that will be mirrored.

It is also important to plan your disk configuration carefully before starting the pool expansion process, as you will not be able to add or remove disks from the pool once the mirror is in place.